# UIViewControllerRepresentable strange deallocation

Tags: swiftui

I have a UIViewController that is used in SwiftUI by a UIViewControllerRepresentable.

When I navigate back from the controller to the SwiftUI view, deinit is not called (as I would expect).

However, when I perform a new navigation to the UIViewControllerRepresentable, deinit is called first (for the previous controller)

Is there something I'm missing here with UIViewControllerRepresentable, why doesn't it get deallocated?

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    deinit() {
        print("This isn't called until the second initiation of the UIViewControllerRepresentable")
    }

}

struct MyViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = MyViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyViewControllerWrapper>) -> MyViewControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType {
    
        let vc = UIViewControllerType(requestType: requestType)
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyViewControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyViewControllerWrapper>) {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: This is long-time known behaviour of NavigationView - it just does not clear last visited view until it is replaced, UIViewControllerRepresentable has nothing to it.

Comment: Thanks, are you able to share where you found out this information?